click() only works after setTimeout, but can't find the dependency
On a mobile version of a webpage (really just if (window.innerWidth <= 1024){}), I have a script to run a click() method on an element (a fullscreen icon) after the user clicks on an image.
It all works as expected when I have a setTimeout(click function, 600).
When I remove the timeout or set it to shorter wait times (100ms <= 500ms), the click() works, but the visuals aren't correct.
I speculate some other styling or script needs to load / run before the click() can be run, and I want to put an eventListener or another MutationObserve on it. But I can't find any difference in document.body before and after the timeout. What am I missing here?
I uploaded a copy of the site here (reminder, script only runs on screen width < 1024):

https://purple-pattern.flywheelsites.com
username / pass: flywheel /
flywheel

I've also included a screen recording showing it working and not working.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12g3MoXIoUn64AM9_BLVDS4ahR4jAi2xO/view?usp=sharing
In the screen recording, look for:

First load: all works as expected. Timeout is 700ms. Background is opaque. Image is clear.
Next several loads: timeout is 100ms - 500ms. Either the background is semi-transparent or the image is dark.
Last load: all works as expected. Timeout is back to 700ms.

Thanks
"use strict";
console.log("sandbox js loaded");

// Loads lightbox images in fullscreen by default on mobile

const bsaPortfolioImg = document
  .getElementsByClassName("fusion-image-carousel")[0]
  .getElementsByTagName("img");

const bsaPortfolioImgFsBtn = document.getElementsByClassName(
  "ilightbox-fullscreen"
);

console.log("bsaPortfolioImg: ", bsaPortfolioImg);
console.log("bsaPortfolioImg[0]: ", bsaPortfolioImg[0]);

console.log("bsaPortfolioImgFsBtn: ", bsaPortfolioImgFsBtn);

function bsaOnElementAvailable(selector, callback) {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
      observer.disconnect();
      callback();
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}


if (window.innerWidth <= 1024) {
  bsaOnElementAvailable(".ilightbox-fullscreen", () => {
    console.log("element available!!");
    // bsaPortfolioImgFsBtn[0].click();

    console.log("document.body before Timeout: ", document.body);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("document.body after Timeout: ", document.body);
      bsaPortfolioImgFsBtn[0].click();
      console.log("clicked");
    }, 600);
  });
}


Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

Is there any error in the console when it fails?

What do you mean by "the visuals aren't correct"? What is it supposed to do, what is it doing instead?

Can you reproduce the problem without the width<1024 requirement? That will make it easier to try to reproduce and debug it.

@Barmar because it's a script I run on top of a 3rd party wordpress website, and because the problem is I don't know what the dependency is (which is the reason for the question), I don't know how to make a minimal reproducible example of it. So I uploaded a copy of the site online, hoping that would provide some insight. Sorry about that.
No errors in console when setTimout is set to any of the lower values.

@Barmar,

"What do you mean by "the visuals aren't correct"? What is it supposed to do, what is it doing instead?"


In the screen recording, look for:

-- First load: all works as expected. Timeout is 700ms. Background is opaque. Image is clear.
-- Next several loads: either the background is semi-transparent or the image is dark.
-- Last load: all works as expected. Timeout is back to 700ms.

@Barmar > "Can you reproduce the problem without the width<1024 requirement? That will make it easier to try to reproduce and debug it"  - the issue is only clearly observable on "mobile" screens because the layout is slightly different than desktop. On desktop, the fullscreen image covers the entire screen, so the overlay isn't very observable.

The clarification should be in the question, not a comment.

Have you tried debugging it in responsive design mode? There's probably an option in your dev tools; in Firefox it's on the top right and looks like a mobile phone and a tablet.

@mykaf yes in the screen recording the browser (Safari) is in responsive design mode (set to iphone screen widths and user-agent).
